# html login and password fields non clickable

Tags: html, css, forms, authentication, click

i am trying to find whats is going on with this...i am not able to click even at nickname nor password...i dont know what is causing this....please help me..!!!!

HTML

```
<header>
      <div id="login">
        <form action="post">
             <fieldset>
              Username: <input type="text" size="30" autofocus>
              Password: <input type="password" size="30">
              <a href="#" class="login">Login</a>
            </fieldset>
        </form>   
      </div> 
        <h1>GreekzUp</h1>
        <h2>Drink us much as you can!!!</h2>
 </header>
```

CSS

```
#login {
    float: right;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:  'Arial', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add name attributes to those inputs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure what's going wrong...
made a JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NLVSV/ and this works...

I did change your

```
#login{
   ....
}
```

with

```
.login {
    ....
}
```